# Add objects one by one when click button MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have added items to the list.But the problem is in here i have added items one by one to the list after button click items.Every time only 1 object shows in the list.

```
 List<Items> _objList = new List<Items>();
    public ActionResult AddNewItems(int ItemId)
    {

        Items items = itemBusiness.GetItemByItemId(ItemId);

        _objList.Add(new Items { ItemId =items.ItemId,ItemName =items.ItemName,
                                 ItemPrice = items.ItemPrice });

        Session["ItemSession"] = _objList;
        return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
    }
```

### Items DTO

```
 public class Items
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public int? ItemBadge { get; set; }
    public DateTime? AddedDate { get; set; }
    public int? AddedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public int? UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    public decimal ItemPrice { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: You are always creating a new list with one item and override the previously saved list in the session, you should retrieve the existing list from the session and use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store the list, then retrieve it to add a new item to it.    That create could be done a couple ways including calling a method that creates if it does not exist and returns that session list as in the

`var _objList = (List<Items>)Session["ItemSession"];`

Just make sure you DO have one so it does not throw an InvalidCastException

This code assumes you DO have a list stored in some "create" method prior to adding another one.

```
public ActionResult AddNewItems(int ItemId)
{
    var _objList = (List<Items>)Session["ItemSession"];
    Items items = itemBusiness.GetItemByItemId(ItemId);
    _objList.Add(new Items { ItemId = items.ItemId,
                             ItemName = items.ItemName,
                             ItemPrice = items.ItemPrice });
    Session["ItemSession"] = _objList;
    return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
}
```

Example alternate, set a property on your class and use that avoiding the cast exception by checking for null and creating if not there yet (and store at end as you have):

```
ItemsHolder.Add(new Items { ItemId = items.ItemId,
                             ItemName = items.ItemName,
                             ItemPrice = items.ItemPrice });
```

Add to your class

```
// the property
public List<Items> ItemsHolder
{
    get
    {
        object ItemsSession = Session["ItemSession"] as List<Items>;

        if (ItemsSession == null)
        {
            ItemsSession = new List<Items>();
            Session["ItemSession"] = ItemsSession;
        }

        return (List<Items>)ItemsSession;
    }
}
```

Side note, just make sure your items are serializable.  You might just want to store a list of `ItemId` and get the name and price as needed to avoid some issues. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/index

Comment: In the _objList.Add section threw an exception called 'System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'' But i checked added items have values

Comment: See how that second example checks for the null, the first is entirely dependent upon an existing session object.  Both need to be able to serialize to the session string.  I make a lot of assumptions as we have no visibility to `Items` here but that is perhaps a new separate question from "how" to manage the list.

Comment: Correct.Thaks a lot.